# Powershell - output progress of command

Tags: powershell

I'm working with a command which was written by someone else, and I'm sending the output to a text file like this:

```
Get-SomeCommand | Out-File C:\temp\temp.txt
```

`Get-SomeCommand` also has a progress bar and what I'd like to do is output the progress to a text file so that I can get another program to read it.

I can work out how much data has been processed from the size of C:\temp\temp.txt, but I don't know what the total size will be when it's finished  so I can't work out the percentage.

Can someone point me in the right direction, or if this can actually be done?

Comment: What is Get-SomeCommand? Is it compiled or can you see how the progress bar is being generated?

Comment: It's compiled and I can't see how it's being generated...